# Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException JavaFX image transition

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, javafx-8, fxml

When i try to add image transition for my JavaFX app, it has thrown this error,I checked the previous questions and answers here in Stackoverflow, but all the solutions were specific for each of those questions only.I am using netbeans IDE.

> Executing H:\thirdf\FinalF\dist\run2135548605\FinalF.jar using
>   platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre/bin/java Exception in
>   Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
>   method    at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
>   file:/H:/thirdf/FinalF/dist/run2135548605/FinalF.jar!/finalf/FXMLDocument.fxml
>
> at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)     at
>   finalf.FinalF.start(FinalF.java:38)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is
>   required.     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)     at
>   finalf.FXMLDocumentController.loadSplashScreen(FXMLDocumentController.java:55)
>     at
>   finalf.FXMLDocumentController.initialize(FXMLDocumentController.java:69)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)    ... 17 more
>   Exception running application finalf.FinalF Java Result: 1

here's the code

SplashFXML.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="574.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.101" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="450.0" fitWidth="560.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@loader.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

FXMLDocument.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="462.0" prefWidth="473.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.101" fx:controller="finalf.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="225.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="212.0" text="Play" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <Button layoutX="126.0" layoutY="312.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="212.0" text="Instructions" />
      <TextField layoutX="126.0" layoutY="141.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="212.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLDocumentController.java

```
package finalf;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane root;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
       try{
       FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Second_Window.fxml"));
       Parent rootl = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
       Stage stage = new Stage();

       stage.setTitle("Foker");
       stage.setScene(new Scene(rootl));
       stage.show();
       }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Can't load new window");
       }
    }


    private void loadSplashScreen() throws IOException{
      StackPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/SplashFXML.fxml"));
      root.getChildren().setAll(pane);
      FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(3),pane);
      fadeIn.setFromValue(0);
      fadeIn.setToValue(1);
      fadeIn.setCycleCount(1);

      fadeIn.play();

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        try {
            loadSplashScreen();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }    

}
```

FinalF.java

```
package finalf;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class FinalF extends Application {

    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event){


    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: if you see clearly there is Null pointer exception on FXMLLoader.java:2579  and it's trying to find file file:/H:/thirdf/FinalF/dist/run2135548605/FinalF.jar!/finalf/FXMLDocument.fxml

Comment: @Gaurav but i added it already ` Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));` in FinalF.java

Comment: it's in your classpath or you can use classloader to get this `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("path")`

Comment: Read little bit about classloader & how we get resource using classloader don't seems to be that complex in you problem

Comment: @Gaurav updated, but still  iam getting the same error :(

Comment: can you debug your code?

Comment: @gaurav when i debug it, i get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146716/discussion-between-gaurav-and-kaw123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's try

1. in *FXMLDocumentController.java*, change the first line in `loadSplashScreen()` method,

from

```
StackPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/SplashFXML.fxml"));
```

to

```
StackPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SplashFXML.fxml"));
```

2. in *FXMLDocument.fxml*, add `fx:id="root"` to the `AnchorPane` section. make it change

from

```
AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="462.0" prefWidth="473.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.101" fx:controller="finalf.FXMLDocumentController"
```

to

```
AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="root" prefHeight="462.0" prefWidth="473.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.101" fx:controller="finalf.FXMLDocumentController"
```

Hope it solves your problem after this two steps.

Comment: dude, you are amazing :D that solved the problem <3 thanks a lot ,almost 3 hours wasted for this. Thanks a lot

Comment: in the AnchorPane element, you cannot just write id="AnchorPane", you have to add fx:id="root".